# Google Maps v2 in a Android Studio app requires Google Play Services update even though it is up-to date

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a navigation drawer with fragments for each page. And in one of my fragments i want to display a mapview. But not in full screen, i want it to be like the top half of screen and below that i will give some contact information for a specific coordinate. 
I tried too many tutorial but i couldn't get this working.

**The Page XML which Map is supposed to be displayed**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/map_background"
tools:context="com.corvega.ztbb.IletisimFragment">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ContactMapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Behind the Map's page JAVA**

```
public class IletisimFragment extends Fragment {
public MapView mapView;
private static GoogleMap googleMap;

public IletisimFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_iletisim, container, false);

    if (googleMap != null)
        setUpMap();
    if (googleMap == null)
    {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment)MainActivity.fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.ContactMapView)).getMap();
        if (googleMap != null)
        {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }

    return rootView;
}

private static void setUpMap()
{
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(41.009471, 28.916134)).title("baslik"));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(41.009471, 28.916134), 12.0f));
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView()
{
    super.onDestroyView();
    if (googleMap != null)
    {
        MainActivity.fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .remove(MainActivity.fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.ContactMapView))
                .commit();
        googleMap = null;
    }
}
```

}

**My AndroidManifest.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<permission android:name="com.arshad.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_icon_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_icon_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_icon_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="my api key was here"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

**dependencies in Build.Gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'
}
```

However my final result is this. I am sure that Google Play Services is up-to date on the phone. So do you have any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: emulator or real device?

Comment: the result is same on both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your gradle file to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
```

unless if you're targeting L Preview

Comment: thanks! at least now i have the controls on my screen but somehow the maps doesn't load.

Comment: Sorry that was because of my faulty api key. Now it works just fine. Your answer did fix my problem. Thanks again.